# Why does Naruto's headband change color?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto Part 1, Naruto's headband was blue. In Naruto Shippuden, his headband was black. In one of the movies, it was red. A shinobi's headband symbolized who you are loyal to, so is there any significance to the headband's color, and if not, why was it repeatedly changed?

Comment: Which movie was it red in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Kuwaly state, there does not appear to be any significance in the color of their [Headband's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Forehead_Protector) strap. The most common of all colors are either the blue or black

> Navy Blue: The most common colour of forehead protectors. Many ninja keep this colour for the entirety of their ninja career.
>
> Black: The second most common colour of forehead protectors. Some, such as Naruto Uzumaki, even switch from blue to black after the timeskip

Now the reason to why they change colors can be due to either

1. They *do* need to be replaced from time to time, especially after difficult training
2. They simply out grown of them, and want to change the color

In Shippuden episode 6, when Naruto is talking with Iruka over ramen, Naruto says to Iruka

> The cloth on the precious Headband you gave me got all tattered

So given that information, Naruto changed his headband due to the fact that it was simply torn and needed to be replaced

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Forehead_Protector) page, there isn't any particular significance to the colors, though some of the variation is based on location/loyalty. Navy and black seem to just both be common colors. Other characters switched color after the timeskip, such as Sakura and Choji, both of whom switched to red.

Theories on why various characters' cloth color changed include [that it's to match their new look](https://www.narutoforums.org/threads/the-explanation-about-the-color-change-of-sakuras-forehead-protector.100927/) or [that it's based on rank](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080818221009AAxq8mi), but there doesn't seem to have been anything specifically said by the creator (that I can find), and neither of those theories are particularly consistent with the rest of the show. It seems more likely that the changes were just done as a part of the stylistic/look changes post-timeskip.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Naruto’s head band changes to match his new color scheme from navy to black. Ino and Sakura both were training in medical ninjutsu so maybe that’s why it’s red.

Comment: Choji wears a red headband in Shippuden and he isn't a medical Ninja

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just your preference, though within reason. I doubt you can have a rainbow headband. There is also a white variation, worn by the Four Celestials.